# Device screen orientation

Tags: screen-orientation

In screen orientation, I want to achieve portrait and reverse portrait orientations only on the Android device. And it should lock the screen in landscape orientation. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Application manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorportrait"
```